# python pass values to other functions in class

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class test():

    def __init__(self,name,method):
        self.name = name
        self.method = method
        self.values = None

    def A(self):
        self.values = []
        # here, I want to fill the values list when 
        # the method is equal to a certain name (in this case 'a')
        # but I want to use these values in the 'S' function no matter what
        if self.name == 'a':
            for i in range(4):
                self.values.append(i)

        if self.method == 'S':
            return self.S()
        if self.method == 'V':
            return self.V()


    def S(self):
        # here I use the self.values (which are related to a) and 
        # I will make some calculations with other values
        # In terms of simplicity I return only the self.values
        return 'S is called:{0}'.format(self.values)

    def V(self):
        return 'V is called:{0}'.format(self.values)

class basic():

    def __init__(self, name, thelist):
        self.name = name
        self.thelist = thelist

    def startp(self):
        name = self.name
        for i in self.thelist:
            yield i.A()
```

I have a test class which is defined as `test('a','V')` , which has a name and a method and a basic class `basic('a',alist)` which takes a name and a list of tests.

My problem is in `A()` function where I want to fill a list with values and pass them to functions `S` and `V`.

These values will be associated with the variable `a` for example.
I want these values in order to use them in the `S` function.

The problem is with the `if self.name =='a'` statement.

So, if I have a `test('a','S')` everything is passed fine, but my tests will contain different values.

Running the code with:

```
 alist = [ test('a','V'), test('b','S')]
 obs = basic('a',alist).startp()
 for i in obs:
     print(i)
```

produces :

```
V is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]
S is called:[]
```

Running with :

```
alist = [ test('a','V'), test('a','S')]
```

produces :

```
V is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]
S is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So, the logic is if the name in `test` is equal to the name in `basic` then use this variables values as reference.But, it will be always one basic name equal to one test name to the `alist`.So, I am using the `if self.name =='a'` but the right thing is `search the list of tests` and `when self.name == a` create `values`.

--------------- UPDATE ------------------------

I just want to populate the `values` list in order to always use it in the `S` function.I must note, that when the `test` has the method `S` , it will always have different name(the first argument) from the `basic` class.

So , this is valid :

```
alist = [ test('a','V'), test('b','S'),test('c','S')]
obs = basic('a',alist).startp()
```

This is not "valid":

```
alist = [ test('a','V'), test('a','S'),test('c','S')]
obs = basic('a',alist).startp()
```

because `test('a','S')` uses the name `a` which is equal to `basic('a',alist)`

Comment: Why is `alist` a list of `test` objects that you then again create `test` objects of in `startp`? Why not make `alist` a list of tuples or dicts?

Comment: @RickyA:The `startp` is where the whole app starts running.I am iterating through my `alist` which contains many `test` objects.I am sorry I didn't understand what you are trying to say.The `alist` will be a list or a numpy array.I don't want to use dictionaries or tuples for now.Thanks

Comment: ok, but then why are you doing `yield test(i.name, i.method).A()` again. `i.A()` should be enough since `i` is already a `test` object

Comment: @RickyA:yes, I just saw it!You are right.

Comment: Why not pass `A` the `name` when called in `startp`?

Comment: yup: `i.A(name)` and test for that in `A` instead.

Comment: @StevenSummers:ah!You are right!it works!Please make it an answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your method `test.A` to take another parameter as such so you can check against it instead of hard-coding the value in.

```
def A(self, name):
    self.values = []
    if self.name == name:
        ...
```

Then in `basic.startp` pass in the value for name for the `basic` instance.

```
for i in self.thelist:
    yield i.A(self.name)
```

---

```
# Testing
alist = [test('a','V'), test('b','S')]
obs = basic('a',alist).startp()
for i in obs:
    print(i)

#V is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]
#S is called:[]

alist = [test('a','V'), test('a','S')]
obs = basic('a',alist).startp()
#V is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]
#S is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]

alist = [test('a','V'), test('a','S')]
obs = basic('b',alist).startp()
#V is called:[]
#S is called:[]

alist = [test('a','V'), test('b','S')]
obs = basic('b',alist).startp()
#V is called:[]
#S is called:[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Hmm.If I use `def A(self,anothername):`
        `self.values = []`
        `if self.name == anothername:`, it doesn't work.It gives me again empty list.I don't understand something here?Thanks

Comment: In what way does it not work? Updated answer with outputs from what I ran. It seem to work as intended.

Comment: Hmm..Sorry but we are again back to my original question.My fault.I want when I have `test('b','S')` and `basic('a',alist0` , to always return the values no matter what `test` has as first argument.I just want to fill the `values` list which corresponds to `'a'` (basic class) .Later, I want to use these values together with other to produce the result of `S`.I have to remove the accepted answer, sorry it is my fault, I made a mistake in a hurry!

Comment: So, the meaning of testing `if self.name == name` is to just create the `values` which I want always to pass them to `S`.These are values specific to `'a'` for example

Comment: That's okay, Back to your question then. It's a bit confusing, if you want to populate `self.values` regardless if `self.name` is `'a' or 'b'` then what is the if statement for?

Comment: Thanks..I updated my post at the end.I want to populate `values` in order to use it always in `S` function.The `values` will be specific to 'a' variable for example (the first argument of `basic` class).I hope it is clear.One solution which may work,it will be to create another function to populate `values` ? And pass the result to 'S`?Maybe.Or if it is a better solution

Comment: One sure way for this to work, will be if I could do something like : `for i in alist` `if i.name == name` fill values, exit loop.Then , in `S` again the same loop ommitting the case where `i.name==name`.But the thing is that I have to do the above in the `S` function and not in the `startp`.I don't know if you have any ideas about this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm just unable to quite grasp what you are trying to do sorry.

Comment: Hmm..Almost there I think using your solution(changed `A` to take `name` and `values`). Please check [here](http://pastebin.com/gwMPiZhh) for details and comments at the end.

Comment: Hmm..I think I solved it! change the line 34 to `if i.name == self.name and i.method != 'S':` and it works!I don't know if I will have any issues in the future though..:).I am accepting your answer since I used your trick.